# Is it possible to get a css variable in RMD?

Tags: java, css, r, r-markdown

I have an .Rmd file where I would like to adapt the style depending on whether it is a mobile version or not - in css it is quite easy to check the window width with @media;

But then, let's say I have a root variable

`--mobile: 1;`

How would I be able to use this variable in an R chunk of a .Rmd file, i.e. how could I retrieve this variable?

Comment: CSS can come from lots of places:  inline code, an external file, etc.  Do you know where this is coming from, or are you hoping to catch it no matter where it was entered?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is essentially impossible, unless you are just parsing a .css file that you're intending to include:

CSS values can only be determined by looking at the .html file produced from the .Rmd file, but at the time the R code is running, the .html file hasn't yet been produced.

One way to get a guess at the value might be to have your R code render an .html file from the same .Rmd you're currently using (and you'll have to be careful that the nested .Rmd doesn't render itself again, in an infinite recursion).  Then parse that .html file to find the active value of that variable within the code chunk that wants to know it.

Comment: So would there be any other way to have in an R chunk let's say a variable mobile =1 if the window width < 600 px and 0 instead?  Or how would I implement something like you have described?

Comment: Couldn't I parse a css file and in the css file I write something like "@media (max-width: 800px) {--mobile:1;} @media not (max-width: 800px) {--mobile:0;}"

Comment: Your first suggestion is definitely impossible.  The window width could be different every time you view the .html file.  You'll need to do that kind of test in Javascript that runs in the browser, not in R code that runs before the .html file is produced.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how could I make something like this possible?

Comment: I think you would have to run both versions of R code, and then decide which one to display and which one to hide at display time.  I don't know how to do that.